# PHP PDO Oracle character type binding error

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, parameters, bind

I have a table in oracle (11g xe) 'bill' which has a structure like below:

```
key_id number(10),
bill_no number(10),
bill_date date,
cons_id_no varchar(10),
cons_no char(15)
```

I am connecting to the database using PHP::PDO like below:

```
public function findByConsumerNumber($consumerNumber) {
   $pdo = new \PDO('oci:dbname=/localhost:1521/xe','kaushik','123');
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM bill WHERE cons_no = :cons_no');
   $stmt->bindParam(':cons_no',$consumerNumber);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $this->findCollection($stmt->fetchAll());
}
```

But on executing I am getting 0 results. But when I change the code as follows, I am getting results:

```
public function findByConsumerNumber($consumerNumber) {
   $pdo = new \PDO('oci:dbname=/localhost:1521/xe','kaushik','123');
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bill WHERE cons_no = '" . $consumerNumber . "'");
   $stmt->execute();
   return $this->findCollection($stmt->fetchAll());
}
```

I am not able to find the actual problem.

Note:  when I try to find results based on cons_id_no as in the first method given above, I am getting results.

Comment: Tried setting PDO to throw exceptions? `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`. You might find out what's going wrong

Comment: @Phil, I am using that. It is showing no errors. Just getting 0 results.

Comment: No you're not. Where is it in your code?

Comment: @Phil, Actually I am using a data mapper pattern and in the connect method of the adapter, I am using ``$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)``. When I found this error, I tried to execute the sql without any abstractions. That code is given above, but I got same results.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake : consumberNumber should be consumerNumber

You should look into Dependency injection, initializing a db connection every time a method is called is crazy.

Comment: Spelling mistake is not the issue. I am using an IDE and code completion deals with it.